# Methode() got multiple values for argumen 'name'

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to do Django3 by example online shop => cart section and I tried this for my cart View

```py
    @require_POST
    def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(MainProduct, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        
        cart.add(product,
                quantity= cd['quantity'],
                override_quantity=cd['override'],
                color =   cd['color'],
                size = cd['size'],

        )
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

and this for cart.py that handle my cart requests

```py
    class Cart(object):

    def __init__(self, request):
        """
        Initialize the cart.
        """
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            # save an empty cart in the session
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def add(self,color,size, product,quantity=1, override_quantity=False):
        """
        Add a product to the cart or update its quantity.

        """
        # self.cart['color'] = color
        # self.cart['size'] = size
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                     'price': str(product.price),
                                     'color' : str(colors),
                                     'size': str(sizes)
                            }

        if override_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
            
            
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()
```

and I have this Error

```
Exception Value: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'
```

but when I ignore color and size that will work with no Error ...

Answer (score 0):

You can save the "color" array in a string with comma on the cookie.